# Laravel 5.2 paginate with relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, eloquent

Trying to get paginator for Eloquent model with relationships:

```
$post->with(['actualBasicStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])->with(['actualExtStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])->whereIn('group_id', $groups);

    $list = $post->paginate($this->paginate); //20
```

But dumping of resulted list item shows no relations in model

---

[image: Laravel's dd()]

---

How can I get related model in paginated list?

Comment: check if the relations of model are correct, post model please.

Comment: I found the problem, `$post` builder need to be assigned to variable.